# ¿Como guardar en bd, las coordenadas que estoy mostrando en un div.innerHTML?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, geolocalización

Buenas, soy nuevo en la comunidad. Mi problema es el siguiente, necesito guardar las coordenadas(latitud y longitud) en mi base de datos cuando la persona haga un registro en mi **Aplicación Web**. Antes de realizar el nuevo ingreso el usuario acepta compartir su ubicación y esta inmediatamente se muestra en un `div` que tengo, lo pueden ver en la siguiente imagen:

[image: Div que muestra latitud y longitud]
**A continuación les muestro el código que tengo dentro del formulario:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    alert("¡Permitenos saber tu ubicación!");

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(mostrarUbicacion);
                    } else {alert("¡Error! Este navegador no soporta la 
Geolocalización.");}

                    function mostrarUbicacion(position) {
                    var latitud = position.coords.latitude;
                    var longitud = position.coords.longitude;
                    var div = document.getElementById("ubicacion");
                    div.innerHTML = "Ubicación actual:" + latitud + "&nbsp;" + longitud;}   

                    function refrescarUbicacion() { 
                    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(mostrarUbicacion);} 
                </script>
```

Necesito saber como puedo pasar el contenido del `div` a mi base de datos, teniendo en cuenta que ya tengo el **PHP** que ejecuta los ingresos de otros campos del formulario. Agradecería que me pudieran ayudar.

**Codigo php para realizar ingresos en bd**
[image: Codigo php para realizar ingresos en bd]

Muchas gracias

**Codigo Formulario**

```html
<form method="post" action="guardar_ingresofinal.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="row" style: aria-hidden="true">
            
                <div class="col-xs-6" >
                <div class="row" style: aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="col-xs-12" align=left>
                
                Estado:
                <select class="selectpicker form-control" id="regestado" name="regestado" required>
                
                        <option value="">Seleccionar...</option>
                       
                        <?php 
                        $query = "SELECT estado FROM estados";
                        $resultado = $mysqli->query($query);
                    
                        WHILE($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row['estado']?>"><?php echo $row['estado']?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                        
                                                  
                </select>
                </div>
                </div> 
                </div>
                
                
                
                <div class="col-xs-6" >
                <div class="row" style: aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="col-xs-12" align=left>
                
                Municipio:
                <select class="selectpicker form-control" id="regmunicipio" name="regmunicipio" data-live-search="true" required>
                
                        <option value="">Seleccionar...</option>
                       
                        <?php 
                        $query = "SELECT idmunicipio, municipio FROM municipios ORDER BY municipio ASC";
                        $resultado = $mysqli->query($query);
                    
                        WHILE($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row['municipio']?>"><?php echo $row['municipio']?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                        
                                                  
                </select>
                </div>
                </div> 
                </div>
                
               
                
                
                 
                <div class="col-xs-12" >
                <div class="row" style: aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="col-xs-12" align=left>
                <p></p>
                
                Institución Educativa: 
                <select class="selectpicker form-control" id="regcolegio" name="regcolegio" data-live-search="true" required>
                       
                        <option value="">Seleccionar...</option>
                       
                        <?php 
                        $query = "SELECT idcolegio, colegio FROM colegios ORDER BY colegio ASC";
                        $resultado = $mysqli->query($query);
                    
                        WHILE($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row['colegio']?>"><?php echo $row['colegio']?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                        
                        
                            
                </select>
                
                <p></p>
                
                
                <div class="col-xs-12" align=center>
                <b>Comentario de la actividad</b> <br>
                </div>
                <textarea name="regdes" rows="4" cols="40" class="col-xs-12" required></textarea> 
                
                
                <p></p>
                
                <div class="row" style: aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="col-xs-12" align=center>
                <p></p>
                <b>Evidencia de la actividad *</b> <br>
                    
                    <input id="file-1" type="file" class="file" multiple=true data-preview-file-type="any" name="imagen">
                   
                
                <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload" aria-hidden="true"></span> Subir archivo
                </button>-->
                </div>
                </div>
                
                <p></p>
                
                <div class="row" style: aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="col-xs-12" align=center>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="enviar"  value="Enviar Registro" />
                <!--Desactivado        
                <input id="btn_listar" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Listar">
                --> 
                </div>
                
                <hr>
                
                <!--Div que muestra ubicacion-->
                <div class="col-xs-12" align=center id="ubicacion"></div>
                <!--<input id="latitud" name="latitud" type="" value="" />-->
                
                
               <script type="text/javascript">
                    if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    alert("¡Permitenos saber tu ubicación!");
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(mostrarUbicacion);
                    } else {alert("¡Error! Este navegador no soporta la Geolocalización.");}
                
                    function mostrarUbicacion(position) {
                    var latitud = position.coords.latitude;
                    var longitud = position.coords.longitude;
                    var div = document.getElementById("ubicacion");
                    div.innerHTML = "Ubicación actual:" + latitud + "&nbsp;" + longitud;} 
                    
                    function refrescarUbicacion() { 
                    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(mostrarUbicacion);} 
                </script>
                
                <!--Fin Div que muestra ubicacion -->
                
                
                </div>
                
                
                </div>
                </div>
                </div> 
            
            
              
            </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: El envío lo dados lo haces por Ajax?

Comment: No, actualmente los otros campos los estoy enviando por metodo post.

Comment: Entonces debes guardar esos dos campos en dos input nuevos que sean de tipo hidden pa que no se vean y así los pueda recibir tu archivo php

Comment: Ya lo he intentado pero no me sale, quizas lo este haciendo mal. Me podrias ayudar?

Comment: Muestra el código del formulario, el php que recibe los datos

Comment: @CamiloVasquez Ya actualice

Comment: Te recomiendo que todos los códigos siempre los subas como tal y no como imagen, y donde esta el formulario con los campos hidden ?

Comment: Dale, aun no lo he creado

Comment: No haz creado el formulario ? entonces como envías los datos?

Comment: Si, mira el codigo que tengo para el formulario. @CamiloVasquez

Comment: @CamiloVasquez amigo una consulta tengo pensando montar el aplicativo en el servidor y colocarle una ip publica para que los usuarios puedan acceder, pero he leido que la geolocalizacion solo funciona con certificados de seguridad HTTPS... no se mucho del tema pero al montarla funcionará o no? Porque si no, ya no le pierdo tiempo a implementar la ubicacion. Gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: Esa pregunta si no te la sé responder, no tengo la más mínima idea :c, la función mostrarUbicacion() se ejecuta apenas ingreso al sitio ?

Comment: Dale no te preocupes. Si, la funcion mostrarUbicacion se ejecuta inmediatamente apenas se ingresa al sitio.

Comment: Pudiste resolverlo? yo también quise capturar las variables en hidden y no los almacenaba cuando asignaba el id, lo extraño es en un campo de texto pude el id y apareció la coordenada, es decir respetaba el valor de la variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

1. Agrega dos campos `hidden` en tu formulario para guardar la longitud y la latitud que se obtienen con la ubicación

   ```
   <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="latitud" name="latitud" required>
   <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="longitud" name="longitud" required>
   ```
2. Cuando se ejecute la función mostrarUbicacion() asignas los valores correspondientes a los 2 campos recién creados

   ```
   document.getElementById("latitud").value = latitud;
   document.getElementById("longitud").value = longitud;
   ```
3. Con esto cuando des `click` al botón `submit` esos dos campos se enviarán junto con el resto de campos de tu formulario y los recibes en tu `php` con el valor de su atributo `name` respectivo

   ```
   $latitud = $_POST['latitud'];
   $longitud= $_POST['longitud'];
   ```

Y posteriormente agregas al `INSERT` y listo, debería de funcionar.

Comment: Buenos dias lo intente pero no me gurda la ubicacion, por favor me puedes dar mas detalles de como seria el codigo completo para guardar en la bd las coor

Comment: @SergioMunoz acabo de notar que tenía un error en el código, wow no se como nadie se percató antes nisiquiera yo, para asignar el value a los elementos se usa un = y no los (), prueba cambiando esto a ver si te da.